# What is sId, gId, mId, bId, cId in QR code and how to get that?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How can I get a value like these:

```
sId=124__ANYSEPARATOR__mId=456__ANYSEPARATOR__bId=678__ANYSEPARATOR__cId=asd12345__ANYSEPARATOR__reqParams=1
```

from the QR code, I am using the package [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) to scan a Qr code but it just provides me the last value like this: "Abbas Jafari".

I just want to get sId, gId, mId, bId, cId from a QR code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting sId, cId and ... from QR code in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146539/getting-sid-cid-and-from-qr-code-in-flutter)

Comment: Can you post your qr code?

Comment: I generate a QR code from the internet, I don't have any specific QR code

Comment: No Clive, it isn't the answer to my question, Please look carefully, there is no answer to that question.

Comment: Decode your qr using https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx, you will get raw data. Check if there is something such as sId, cId etc.

Comment: Thanks @rrttrr, but there is no value about sId, cId.
I am using this site https://www.qr-code-generator.com/ to generate a QR code.

Comment: I read about qr codes but couldn't find anything such as sId, cId.

Answer (score 0):

A QR code is simply an image representing binary data, which, by typical convention, is treated as text. In other words, the QR code simply represents text.

The text obtained by decoding a QR code is just the text that was given when it was encoded -- nothing more or less. You will not be able to "get" anything from a QR code that was not present in the text that was encoded. Any additional fields or information you want from the QR code will have to be encoded into it.

Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Standards) for some standards and conventions relating to QR code encodings.